# MVC4 WebApi OData $count not working with IQueryable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a simple Get action in a Controller in MVC4:

```
// GET /branches
// returns a list of available branches
[Queryable]
public IQueryable<string> Get() {
    return BranchesRepository.GetBranchNames().AsQueryable();
}
```

This works perfectly when I call it just with a GET and even with some OData options like $top, $skip and $filter.
But it doesn't work when I call it with $count.

e.g:

```
/branches/$count
```

returns

```
[]
```

whereas I'd expect to see a number.

The response header gives me a version for asp.net that I'm using

```
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
```

Is the $count parameter broken in this version? Or is there something I can do to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are still using beta/RC version of Web API? IF so, only $top, $skip, $orderby and $filter were supported.
Moreover, `QueryableAttribute` was removed in the RTM release.

OData is now supported in Web API only via a preview package http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.

But that does not support $count at the moment anyway.